# Why my ordering by linq does not work

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Trying to order logs by logtype or by logType and thenBy DateTime but does not work.What am I missing?

```
      public enum LogType
    {
        Fatal,
        Error,
        Warn,
        Info,
        Debug,
        None,
    }
    public class Log
    {
        public DateTime LoggedDateTime { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public LogType LoggedType { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("LogType: {0} Datetime: {1} Message: {2}", LoggedType, LoggedDateTime, Message);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var logFatal = new Log
                               {
                                   LoggedDateTime = new DateTime(2011, 2, 22),
                                   Message = "Hi am a Fatal message",
                                   LoggedType = LogType.Fatal
                               };

            var logInfo = new Log
            {
                LoggedDateTime = new DateTime(2013, 2, 22),
                Message = "Hi I am a Info message",
                LoggedType = LogType.Info
            };

            var logError = new Log
            {
                LoggedDateTime = new DateTime(2010, 2, 22),
                Message = "Hi I am a Error message",
                LoggedType = LogType.Error
            };

            var logWarning = new Log
            {
                LoggedDateTime = new DateTime(2014, 2, 22),
                Message = "Hi I am a Warning message",
                LoggedType = LogType.Warn
            };
            List<Log> logs = new List<Log> { logWarning, logError, logInfo, logFatal };

            Console.WriteLine("Not Ordered");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            logs.ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine(x.LoggedType));



            var orderedLogs = logs.OrderBy(x => x.LoggedType == LogType.Fatal)
                .ThenBy(x => x.LoggedType == LogType.Error)
                .ThenBy(x => x.LoggedType == LogType.Warn)
                .ThenBy(x => x.LoggedDateTime).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("Ordered by logType fatal first and NOT WORKING");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            orderedLogs.ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine(x.LoggedType));

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Ordered by logType fatal first and NOT WORKING");//NOT WORKING
            List<Log> orderedFatal = logs.OrderBy(x => x.LoggedType == LogType.Fatal).ToList();
            orderedFatal.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.LoggedType));

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Sorted by datetime AND WORKS"); //THIS IS THE ONLY ONE THAT WORKS
            logs.Sort((x,y)=>x.LoggedDateTime.CompareTo(y.LoggedDateTime));
            logs.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.LoggedDateTime));


            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: You aren't writing your own logger, are you? bad bad idea. [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) et al are your friends.

Comment: I am not writing my own logger at all.We are using log4net and I am tired of looking at massive log pages. I just want a quick filter and sort.I know there are software out there but they are not free and I cannot install third party software where I work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `false` is ordered before `true`.
Thus first in your order come those that are not Fatal. Out of those first come those that are not Error etc.

You can use inequalities to make it work:

```
x => x.LoggedType != LogType.Fatal
```

etc.

or use `OrderByDescending` and `ThenByDescending`.

But I'd prefer to give an order of the enum:

```
public enum LogType : int
    {
        Fatal = 5,
        Error = 4,
        Warn = 3,
        Info = 2,
        Debug = 1,
        None = 0,
}
```

and then just use this value:

```
var orderedLogs = logs.OrderByDescending(x => x.LoggedType);
```

Comment: @Ivanov thanks for your example.Would this work.
            var orderedLogs = logs.OrderByDescending(x => (int)x.LoggedType)
                .ThenBy(x=>x.LoggedDateTime).ToList(); The idea is to show all the latest logs ordery by importance if you like an datetime(the latest)

Comment: @user231465: You don't need to cast - just use `logs.OrderByDescending(x => x.LoggedType)`

Answer (score 0):

Both your `logWarning` and `logError` have `LoggedType = LogType.Error` !

Another point: you should implement/use an [`IComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336756) for `LogType`... see MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx

Bascially something like:

```
public class LogComparer : IComparer<Log>
{
    public int Compare(Log x, Log y)
    {
        if ( x == y ) return 0;
        if ( x.LoggedType == y.LoggedType ) return 0;
        if ( x.LoggedType == LogType.Fatal ) return 1;
        if ( y.LoggedType == LogType.Fatal ) return -1;
        // etc.
    }
}

// Usage similar to this
logs.OrderBy(x => x, new LogComparer());
```

Comment: corrected that.Thanks.Do you mean my enum should implement IComparer.Could you show me how you would do that?

Comment: @user231465 I added a link where you can see a sample implementation

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like:

```
var orderedLogs = logs.GroupBy(l => l.LoggedType)
                    .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                    .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(l => l.LoggedDateTime)).ToList();
```

Comment: @Ankur.Thanks for your reply.Tried that but either I have created a sample with bad data or does not work.The idea is I want to have the latest log at the top filtered first fatal then error then warn then info etc...

Comment: Ok, you just need to use `g.OrderByDescending` .. Please check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the collection by the field LoggedType, then by the field LoggedDateTime in the following code:

```
var orderedLogs = logs.OrderBy(x => x.LoggedType) // not x => x.LoggedType == LogType.Fatal
    .ThenBy(x => x.LoggedDateTime).ToList();
```

I think there will be sorting by integer representation of enum. So with your enum there will be Fatal, Error, Warn etc. Or you can use IComparer (from Yahia answer) for your own definition rules of comparison.